# Linearisation of time-varying system $\dot{x}=A(t)x+B(t)u+c(t)$

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

I am trying to linearize the following **affine** relationship where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, u \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and $ c \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$$\dot{x}(t)=f(x,u,t)=A(t)x(t)+B(t)u(t)+c(t)$$

Defining the equilibrium point, $\bar{x}$ to be where $\dot{x}=0$, I find that this equilibrium point must vary with time:

$$\bar{x}(t)=-A(t)^{-1}\left[B(t)\bar{u}(t)+c(t)\right]$$

**Problem:** when I try to linearise around the above fixed point $(\bar{x},\bar{u}$) using the perturbation variables $\delta x=x-\bar{x}$ and $\delta u=u-\bar{u}$, in an attempt to re-write the system as:

$$\delta\dot{x}=A(t)\delta{x}+B(t)\delta{u}$$

I get stuck since to me it seems that $\delta\dot{x}=\dot{x}-\dot{\bar{x}}$ with $\dot{\bar{x}}\ne0$.

Doesn't this contradict the fact that $f(\bar{x},\bar{u},t)=\dot{\bar{x}}=0 \Longrightarrow \dot{\bar{x}}=0$?

Basically, I don't see how to linearise this time varying system around an equilibrium point.

Comment: $\bar{x}(t)$ and $\bar{u}(t)$ should satisfy $\dot{\bar{x}}=f(\bar{x},\bar{u},t)$, namely if $f(\bar{x},\bar{u},t)=0$, but $\bar{x}(t)$ is not constant then this would contradict the dynamics of the system.

Comment: Ok! So does this system have an equilibrium point or trajectory?

Comment: You can always come up with a trajectory simply by simulating the system starting from any initial condition while applying some known input.

Comment: However if $c(t)$ always lies in the span of $B(t)$ then there exists a $\bar{u}(t)$ such that $B(t)\,\bar{u}(t) + c(t)=0$. In that case you could choose $\bar{x}(t)=0$ as equilibrium point.